# Can't connect to SQL Server using IP

Tags: sql-server

I have an instance of SQL Server in a VPS, and I have configured all TCP connection(dynamic ports set to null, and ports set to 1533) and I have already made sure it is enabled.

I have created SQL Server login and made sure both windows and sql server authentications are enabled.

However I still get the `A network related or instance related ...` error.

I tried logging in with:

1- Only ip address

2- IP:Port (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1533)

3- IP\InstanceName (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\InstanceName)

4- IP\InstanceName,Port (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\InstanceName,1533)

5- IP:Port\InstanceName (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1533\InstanceName)

All have failed with the same error.

Comment: Attempts 4 and 5 aren't valid - don't bother with them. Troubleshoot each segment: First log on locally to the VPS server and confirm you can connect locally. Then make sure you have enabled remote connections in SQL Server. Then confirm the external IP address is valid and from your external client, try `telnet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 1533`.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: Already done before posting the question

Comment: You didn't mention the SQL server version and OS. Try adding the firewall rules and also enable the TCP connection in the configuration manager.

Comment: @Khan: OS Win Server 2012 R2 and SQL Server 2016

Comment: You need to add 4 inbound and  4 outbound rules for TCP port, UDP port, Sqlbrowser.exe, and Sqlsrvr.exe.  Also, in SQL Server configuration manager, under SQL Server Network Configuration, check the Protocols for SQLInstance. It should be enabled, and also in IP addresses tab, specify the port number at the very last section (IPAll section). Remove value (0 or anything else) from TCP dynamic ports. Check if it works.

Comment: @Khan: All enabled, and that I even checked my internet connection trying to connect to other servers and it is fine.

Comment: Ah, I see you mentioned that in your question.... But you didn't try adding firewall rules for TCP and UDP Port  1533 and for SqlBrowser.exe and SqlServr.exe?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148005/discussion-between-khan-and-arrrr).

Comment: @Khan: yes, this is not a firewall problem, because I have multiple VPS hosted by the same company, and I have SQL Server 2016 only on this one, the other VPSs use SQL 2014 and never experienced any issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides configuring the TCP connection in SQL Configuration manager, making sure TCP protocol is enabled and  (dynamic ports set to null, and ports set to 1533 or whatever) , You may need to add the firewall rules as [mentioned here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-a-windows-firewall-for-database-engine-access).

**And DON'T forget to restart the services after modifying the configuration.**

Comment: So... you tried everything and you know its not a firewall problem but... this is the accepted answer? This is a low quality question and answer